# Get private key .pfx in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, private-key

How to I extract private key/public key in digital signature `.pfx` format using PHP?

I want to encrypt data with my private key `.pfx` but I got an error when I open it using .pfx format. Another question: is it possible to extract the keys with `.pfx` format? or should I use the `.pem` format? Or is it possible to encrypt the data using `.pfx` format?

Comment: Have you searched for this? Or tried something to achive this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP has a function to read this certificate:

```
$data = file_get_contents('/path/to/cert.pfx');
$certPassword = 'your password';
openssl_pkcs12_read($data, $certs, $certPassword);
var_dump($certs);
```

But to encrypt data with this certificate, you'll need the other PHP openssl functions.